# Stop the loop in time in Python.

Tags: python

I have five loops in my code and I want to stop each loop by the time I set. My code is:

```
nw=1000
for i in range(nw):
    w_list.append(-3+0.006*i)
    chi_1=0
    chi_2=0
    k=1
    while k<10:
            now_1=time.time()
            l=1
            while l<10:
                    now_2=time.time()
                    n_1=0
                    while n_1<10:
                            now_3=time.time()
                            n_2=0
                            while n_2<5:
                                    now_4=time.time()
                                    chi_2+=(e1_vecs[n_1,0]*e1_vecs[n_1,k]*e_vecs[2*n_2,0]*e_vecs[2*n_2,l])**2*(1.0/(w_list[i]+(E0-e_vals[l]-k*w_b+b*w_b)-0.001j))+(e1_vecs[n_1,0]*e1_vecs[n_1,k]*e_vecs[2*n_2+1,0]*e_vecs[2*n_2+1,l])**2*(1.0/(w_list[i]-(E0-e_vals[l]-k*w_b+b*w_b)+0.001j))
                                    n_2+=1
                                    stop_4=time.time()-now_4
                                    time.sleep(1.0-stop_4)
                            n_1+=1
                            stop_3=time.time()-now_3
                            time.sleep(1.0-stop_3)
                    l+=1
                    stop_2=time.time()-now_2
                    time.sleep(1.0-stop_2)
            k+=1
            stop_1=time.time()-now_1
            time.sleep(1.0-stop_2)
    chi_on.append(chi_2.imag)
```

But my method does not work... Do you have any good suggestion? I am a beginner on Programming...

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want to abort and jump out of the loop at a certain time or do you want to sleep for a bit after each iteration?

Comment: What exactly should the behaviour be?

Comment: @wdh I would like to jump out of the loop at a certain time. So that I will not spent to long time on this calculation even though I set too large parameters..

Comment: @sky Ok, I've got it. I've added an answer below, please let me know how you get on and accept the answer as the correct one if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[time.sleep](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) is the wrong method to use, sleep takes in a number of seconds and then forces your program to wait for that amount of time. Instead, you just want your while loops to not run if you have taken too long.

Try something like:

```
MAX_TIMEOUT = 100 # Max seconds before we abort

stop_time = time.time() + MAX_TIMEOUT

nw=1000
abort = False
for i in range(nw):
    w_list.append(-3+0.006*i)
    chi_1=0
    chi_2=0
    k=1
    while k<10 and not abort:
        l=1
        while l<10 and not abort:
            n_1=0
            while n_1<10 and not abort:
                n_2=0
                while n_2<5 and not abort:
                    chi_2+=(e1_vecs[n_1,0]*e1_vecs[n_1,k]*e_vecs[2*n_2,0]*e_vecs[2*n_2,l])**2*(1.0/(w_list[i]+(E0-e_vals[l]-k*w_b+b*w_b)-0.001j))+(e1_vecs[n_1,0]*e1_vecs[n_1,k]*e_vecs[2*n_2+1,0]*e_vecs[2*n_2+1,l])**2*(1.0/(w_list[i]-(E0-e_vals[l]-k*w_b+b*w_b)+0.001j))
                    n_2+=1

                    # We check here if we need to abort
                    if time.time() >= stop_time:
                        abort = True # This will force the while loops to end
                        print 'Aborted because we took too long!' #Probably a good idea to log this somewhere
                n_1+=1
            l+=1
        k+=1
    chi_on.append(chi_2.imag)

    if abort:
         break #No point staying in the forloop if we need to abort
```

Comment: It is perfect solution for my requirement!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
delay = 100  # some time in seconds
start_time = time.time()


while True:
    if start_time + (delay * 5) >= time.time():
         break
    while True:
         if start_time + (delay * 4) >= time.time():
             break
         while True:
             ...
             ...
```